# Sort granules using provided list of featureids in WMS request to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, mosaic, image-mosaic, cql-filter

Quick question on GeoServer image mosaics (using ImageMosaic plugin) with overlapping rasters: I’m filtering the WMS query by featureid and ideally the order in which the rasters are ‘stacked’ would be controlled by their appearance in the array of feature IDs I provide in the request (similar to the "[LockRaster](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/mosaic-rules.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_D8C9EC456733494CB7A7588588682123)" mosaic rule in Esri mosaic datasets) So if I had a wms request with `featureid=id1,id2`, I’d get id1 raster over the id2 raster. and if I flipped the order to id2,id1, I’d get the opposite. Is there any way to do this?

I guess more precise terminology would be: how do I get granule sorting to follow featureid listing, as opposed to specifying a field name using the sortby option. Is there a way to allow the client to specify this ordering arbitrarily?

Here's what a request might look like:
`https://geoserverLocation.co/geoserver/store/ows?width=...&height=...&bbox=...&crs=...&format=image/png&request=GetMap&service=WMS&styles=&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&layers=...&featureid=layer.id1,layer.id2`

including `sortby=featureid` results in the features being sorted by featureid, but as reflected in the table, not my arbitrary ordering in the request. I think this is expected behavior, but I'm wondering if there's a way to order granules arbitrarily using client-side input.

###### use case:

My app allows users to reorder the list of granules in the UI of a web app, I need to match the sorting order of granules with the (arbitrary) order set by the user. I'm able to do this using Esri backends (see LockRaster link above), but haven't quite found a way to do it in the open source side of things.

Perhaps there's a CQL way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: did you try putting the featureid into the sort field?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've updated the question with some more details. The short answer is that providing a sort field appears to sort it based on the order of that field in the underlying table instead of the list of ids provided (I think this is expected behavior). So specifying featureid as the sort field doesn't work in this case.

Comment: so can you order the granules in the order you  need in the table?

Comment: The desired order is arbitrary and decided at runtime by the user on the client side, so it's not something I can know in advance unfortunately.

Comment: I think that will require additional code

Comment: in the sense of modifications to GeoServer itself?

Comment: well the underlying GeoTools code I think